# It is not possible enable Canonical Partners on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I can not enable the *Canonical Partners* in my new installation of Ubuntu 18.04.

I try to do it from the *Canonical Partners* tab on *Software & Updates*.

When I click on the checkbox, it stays deselected.

Comment: It should ask for a password.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on clean Ubuntu 18.04 LTS GNOME and MATE (using Xorg). What is your Ubuntu flavor? Are you using Wayland? Does other options in *Software & Updates* working (such as selecting other mirror - *Download from*)?

Comment: @N0rbert I selected another mirror (Main server), then asked me for the password and now I can check the Canonical Partners option. Is it a known bug?

Comment: @angelcervera I'm not sure, but it may be related to the [bug 1727908](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1727908) or [bug 1720517](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1720517).

Comment: @N0rbert Yes, looks like it is the same problem. If you answer listing both bugs, I will mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to select another mirror in *Software & Updates* - Download From: Main Server, then it should ask password. Then try again to enable *Canonical Partners* repository.

Really it seems to be a bug - one of [bug 1727908](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1727908) or [bug 1720517](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1720517).

Comment: perfectly working with the above solution in Ubuntu 18.04.2

Comment: This solution works with Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS